# Move md-subheader in front of element (z-index?)

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-material

[image: This is what I see when I scroll]I am just starting out with web-development and consider myself to be a novice when it comes to CSS and HTML.

In the below snippet I cannot get the `md-subheader` to move on top of the `md-fab-speed-dial`. The `md-fab-speed-dial` is clickable through the `md-subheader`. How can I move either the `md-subheader` in front or move the `md-fab-speed-dial` move behind ??

```
<md-content style="height: 900px;" flex>
            <section>
                <md-subheader class="md-primary">Songs</md-subheader>
                <md-list layout-padding>
                    <div layout="row" ng-repeat="song in songs">
                        <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-click="playSong(song)" flex>
                            <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
                                <h3>{{ song.title }}</h3>
                                <h4>{{ song.album }}</h4>
                                <p>{{ song.year }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </md-list-item>
                        <md-fab-speed-dial md-direction="left" md-open="demo.isOpen" class="md-scale" ng-mouseenter="demo.isOpen=true" ng-mouseleave="demo.isOpen=false" style="position: relative;">
                            <md-fab-trigger>
                                <md-button aria-label="menu" class="md-fab md-primary md-hue-3">
                                    <md-icon md-svg-src="assets/icons/queue_music.svg" aria-label="plalist"></md-icon>
                                </md-button>
                            </md-fab-trigger>
                            <md-fab-actions>
                                <md-button aria-label="add-playlist" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini" ng-click="">
                                    <md-tooltip md-direction="top" md-visible="tooltipVisible" md-autohide="false">
                                        Add to playlist
                                    </md-tooltip>
                                    <md-icon md-svg-src="assets/icons/playlist_add.svg"></md-icon>
                                </md-button>
                            </md-fab-actions>
                        </md-fab-speed-dial>
                    </div>
                </md-list>
            </section>
        </md-content>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing `.md-fab-speed-dial`. It would be helpful if you provided the applicable CSS and the generated markup.

Comment: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdFabSpeedDial
I honestly have no idea how to figure out where to find the CSS. I have not tried adding any custom CSS apart from the one provided with angular-material.